# HDFS EC Why do small files get bigger

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Here are the files stored by EC

```
Found 1 items
-rwx--x--x   1  hiidoagent hdfs       RS-6-3-1024k       3846 2022-09-08 21:28 hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/event_type=listStatus_par/part-00000-09410305-ccd9-4295-b36e-b7ab1e38d3a4.c000
Found 1 items
-rwx--x--x   1  hiidoagent hdfs       RS-6-3-1024k       5737 2022-09-08 21:22 hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/event_type=listStatus_tab/part-00000-56a03378-bc29-42e1-ac59-8b145a9dc092.c000
Found 1 items
-rwx--x--x   1  hiidoagent hdfs       RS-6-3-1024k       6078 2022-09-08 21:27 hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/event_type=open/part-00000-3e1a11b3-2d52-4d0e-99ab-aa0c391ce847.c000 

hdfs dfs -du -h  hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/*/
3.8 K  15.0 K  hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/event_type=listStatus_par/part-00000-09410305-ccd9-4295-b36e-b7ab1e38d3a4.c000
5.6 K  22.4 K  hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/event_type=listStatus_tab/part-00000-56a03378-bc29-42e1-ac59-8b145a9dc092.c000
5.9 K  23.7 K  hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220907/event_type=open/part-00000-3e1a11b3-2d52-4d0e-99ab-aa0c391ce847.c000
```

How is this total size calculated, for example 5.9*?=23.7?

---

```
 RS-3-2-1024k          0 2022-09-13 17:55 hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220912

hdfs dfs -du -h hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top

15.2 K  45.6 K  hdfs://yycluster06/hive_warehouse/freshman.db/ec_hive_hot_data_top/dt=20220912
```

What IS THE MEANING OF EC FOR SMALL FILES, WHICH IS THE SAME SIZE AS 3xReplication, AND WHAT IS THE FORMULA FOR THIS?

3 xreplication 15.2 * 3 = 45.6

Rs-3-2-1024 K 15.2(Data blocks)+2(Parity Blocks)*15.2=45.6?

Comment: Typically compression: https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.10/scaling-namespaces/topics/hdfs-increasing-storage-capacity-with-hdfs-compression.html

Comment: This is compression related, I want to know the EC storage size calculation formula.

Comment: There will not be a formula. Each file will compress differently. So every file will have a different formula depending on what is inside the file and how well it compressed.

Answer (score 0):

I first selected small files for Hadoop archive and then EC storage, which greatly reduced the storage space.